# forking but not exiting

Tags: c, unix, forking

It is normal for the child in a [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to call `exec()` or `_exit()`.

Are there any realistic scenarios where the *child* might *return* from the function that called `fork()` instead?

```
void foo() {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
     ...
     return; //<-- the child is going to unwind the cloned call stack
  }
  ...
```

So what legitimate uses are there for a forked child returning?  Are there any standards that govern this?

Comment: I think the canonical example of this is creating an identical process for different clients in a client-server architecture.

Answer (score 2):

A trivial example of where the function calling `fork` is supposed to return in both the parent and the child is if the function calling `fork` is a simple wrapper function, and the caller of *that* function is the one that chooses what to do in the parent, and what in the child. A simple wrapper function might not make much sense for pure C, but POSIX C++ bindings could legitimately want to provide a `posix::fork()` function that simply calls the global `fork()` function, but can be declared in a header that does not pollute the global namespace.

caveman gave a good less trivial example in a comment on your question.

The relevant standards address this by not addressing it. The description of `fork()` is specified without any restrictions on returning from the function calling it, so implementations can't choose to disallow that.

It's like how the description of `putchar` doesn't say that implementations can't choose not to print `'a'`, but if an implementation did that, I'm pretty sure we'd be in perfect agreement that that's not what the standards say, that's not what the standards meant to say, and interpreting it like that is just silly.

Answer (score 1):

A child calling  `exec` is not terminated, it is replaced by a new program (running in the *same* [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)).

And the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall may fail for several reasons (so you always should handle such a failure). Then execution continues after the `exec` !

Read e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming/) for details. It has at least a whole chapter about these issues.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear; I've added some example code to clarify my question.